# Starteam shortcut file

Tags: command-line, shortcut, starteam

Is it possible to create StarTeam shortcut, opening project and overriding working directory?

Is it possible to create one StarTeam shortcut, opening several projects at a time?

Problem is: I have several solutions, which use the same StarTeam project, and I have to manually change working folder very often (View -> Properties -> Working folder). It is not possible to share data between solutions: local view should be located in separate place for each solution.

Comment: StarTeam... oh, you have my sympathies, my friend

Comment: I disagree with the user who voted to close, saying it "Belongs on SuperUser.com." VCS questions are common here, and, in my opinion, on-topic. Using a VCS correctly has *everything* to do with programming.

Answer (score 1):

You could create different views for each project. Different views can have different working folders; in fact, they do by default. Keep in mind, a view can be set to behave pretty much the same as the default view, with regards to which revisions of files you see. But they can have their own working folders. The downside of this technique is that Change Requests and the like will also be "in the view," so moving them will not necessarily affect other views. But given that you are working on an entirely separate projects, that might not be all such a bad thing. As usual, you should experiment with this in a test project, and make sure you're happy with the behavior, before using it on your "life" repository.

Answer (score 1):

The override/alternate directory for each project and folder is maintained inside a local file - not on the server.  The default working folder is kept on the server, and any time you update it the changes are propigating to all other users.

The shortcut xml has no place to specify a working folder.

If you don't need the StarTeam GUI, stcmd allows you to specify a new working folder for most operations with the -rp and -fp flags.

If the projects that need this common library code are in their own views, you could also share the common project into a new subfolder within those other projects.  You can use a relative path for this new subfolder that includes .. to move it outside the containing project's folder.  This lets you use common code in many projects while allowing you to specify the location of that common code per project.

Shares come with some overhead, so be aware, but other than that it would probably work for what you're trying to do.